# Enterprise Architect - Cancel Connectors Bridges

Tags: uml, diagram, enterprise-architect, tool-uml

This might be a silly question but still - when two connectors cross each other the EA creates a bridge.
Any way to cancel that so it'll basically be two straight lines crossing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools|Options|Diagram|Enable Connector line jumps
[image: Connector line jumps settings]