# How to use Enterprise Architect line jumps for connectors

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I have created a Deployment Diagram with Enterprise Architect 12.1.1227, the option to enable connector line jumps is checked. But they do not appear in the diagram where two dependency connectors are crossing. How can I force them to appear in my diagram? Am I missing something? The three red circles in my screenshot should have line jumps.

[image]

See this question how to not use line connectors: [Enterprise Architect - Cancel Connectors Bridges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944035/enterprise-architect-cancel-connectors-bridges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EA's renderer does generally not create hops for dashed connectors. You might send a feature request. But don't hold your breath.

Comment: Okay :-) I think I can replace most depedencies with communication flows (which are more precise and solid lines).